# Exclude option for SelectInput that removes a Plot from the Viz?

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I have 4 `SelectInputs`, each one that pulls data from a `.csv` and plots it using `dygraphs`.  At the moment, all 4 of the inputs show up by default, but I want to incorporate an option (maybe a `CheckboxInput`) that will allow me to `Exclude` the chart in that `SelectInput` from being graphed.

Is there a way for me to do this without loading in an empty dataset?  Does anyone know what the best method to accomplish this would be?

**Update:**
So I currently have the following for the first of my 4 data sources:

```
dataSource1 <- reactive({
  validate(
    need(input$dataSelection1 != "No Chart Selected", "Please choose Dataset")
  )
```

But how do I make it so that if I want to remove dataSource1, that it doesn't put the error message up?  For example, if I choose 3 plots, but then want to remove the plot from DataSource1, it brings up this error message.  So I think the issue is in my expression.

Comment: are the 4 SelectInputs coming from 4 different datasets or from the same dataset?

Comment: Each `SelectInput` contains about 50 datasets with about 10 channels for each dataset.  So, the user can select either the same or different dataset/channel combination.